# Connecting to Lightsail app on Cloudflare encountering redirect loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, cloudflare, amazon-lightsail

The frontend of my webapp cannot connect to the backend. The backend is hosted on AWS Lightsail, and both the frontend and backend DNS is routed using Cloudfront CDN.

**Structure of app**

1. Containerised app in NodeJS, running HTTP server on ExpressJS (receiving on port 3000)

   - Allowed-Origin is set to my website's frontend, `https://frontend.domain.com`
2. AWS Lightsail container deployment with the following configurations:

   - port 3000 opened to HTTP protocol
   - default public domain `https://name.rng.region.cs.amazonlightsail.com`
   - TLS certificate verification is already completed
3. Cloudfront DNS CNAME routing `https://backend.domain.com` to the aforementioned Lightsail public domain

   - Proxying is enabled
   - SSL/TLS encryption mode is Flexible, and Always use HTTPS is enabled

**Things I've tried**

When the front-end, `frontend.domain.com`, attempts to send a request using the fetch API to the backend at `backend.domain.com`, analysing the browser's network inspector reveals:

- the ORIGIN request returns "CORS does not succeed"
- the subsequent POST request is sent and returns "NS_ERR_DOM_BAD_URI"
- nothing appears in the Lightsail container's logs, indicating that the Lightsail instance probably did not even receive the request. Ordinarily, both the successful ORIGIN and POST requests would show up in the logs with 200 return codes.

When I attempt to connect to `backend.domain.com` directly through the browser, I expect to see the text "Health check successful!", which is what happens if I connect directly via the Lightsail public domain URI. Instead, analysing the browser's network inspector reveals that a redirect loop occurs.

Note that, previously in development, I was previously sending requests from the frontend to the backend using the Lightsail public domain directly, which was working fine.

I suspect this may be an issue with the HTTP/HTTPS configurations. I would appreciate a more in-depth explanation of where my configuration went wrong and why, along with what steps I should take to correct my mistakes. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that CORS issues doesn't reached the backend endpoint, but that is the usual behaviour.

You should have two endpoints.

1. Cors Preflight

```
map '/flight.xml' do
    run lambda { |env| [200, { 'Content-Type'  => 'application/xml',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'            => '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'       => true
    }, [.. web page... ]
end
```

2. Your backend endpoint

```
   map '/catalogo.json' do
     run lambda { |env| [200, { 'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'            => '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'       => true
    }, [. web page..] 
  end
```